# Oracle Nulls First

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, null

I need help with sorting results of a query on Oracle where I need NULLS to be at the top.

```
MIN(SYSDATE - expiry) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SYSDATE - expiry DESC NULLS FIRST) AS active
```

The result for that goes something like:

```
ID      NAME               ACTIVE
=================================
4       John Smith         139
4       John Smith         NULL
4       John Smith         2700
7       Martha Snow        NULL
```

I want it so that it will sort the result like so:

```
ID      NAME               ACTIVE
=================================
4       John Smith         NULL
4       John Smith         139
4       John Smith         2700
7       Martha Snow        NULL
```

Thanks to those who will help!

Comment: Ha! It looks like I can sort it on the ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY active ASC NULLS FIRST

Comment: why you orde by sysdate, but no date in your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is just assigning values to the third column (presumably).  It is not ordering the entire data set.  Results sets are *unordered*, unless the outer query has an `order by`.

So:

```
select . . .
from . . .
order by id, active asc nulls first;
```

If these are the only three columns, then you probably don't even need the `keep`.  Just:

```
select id, name, (sysdate - expiry) as active
from . . .
order by id, active asc nulls first;
```

Comment: Yes, I figured this out by trying it after I posted the question. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4e32/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( ID, NAME, ACTIVE ) AS
          SELECT 4, 'John Smith', 139 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'John Smith', NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'John Smith', 2700 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'Martha Snow', NULL FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Data
ORDER BY ID, ACTIVE ASC NULLS FIRST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4e32/1/0)**:

```
| ID |        NAME | ACTIVE |
|----|-------------|--------|
|  4 |  John Smith | (null) |
|  4 |  John Smith |    139 |
|  4 |  John Smith |   2700 |
|  7 | Martha Snow | (null) |
```

Comment: Yes, I did figure as such. Thanks for providing an answer though.